# Provide data for certain fields at runtime in Bogus

Tags: c#, bogus

I'm currently creating a set of fake data rules using Bogus. These are going to be used by a set of mocked services. By this I mean I'm creating a mock of a search service that is providing faked data back.

For most of the services, the search criteria that has been input should influence the data that is output (e.g. if you a service to search for organizations based in Mexico, the faked data should only include addresses based in Mexico). If you search for Organizations with names beginning with "Micro*", I want to be able to use this input to influence how the data is produced.

So far I've been able to do this by sub-classing `Faker` and providing my own `Generate` method that takes some input data. I can then call the `Faker.Generate()` method, allow it to provide some data, and then change certain fields before passing it back.

This method works to a point but isn't particularly flexible and I feel there should be a better way to do this.  I've pasted a sample of this workaround below.

```cs
// This shows my current workaround
public static Organization Generate(string searchCode)
{
    var organization = Faker.Generate();
    organization.Code = searchCode;
    return organization;
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Bogus; is it required? If not, this would be super easy to do with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: The purpose of Bogus is that it generates actual data e.g. names, addresses, phone numbers etc. It does randomly normally. I'm looking to make this non-random in some situations

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a lot of ways you could do this but it really depends on your scenario. The first thing you should do is consider how deep or complex your object graphs are.

#### So, as a rough guide...

- If your object graphs are deep and complex, consider faking objects with the `Faker` facade. That means creating `static` factory methods like:

```cs
void Main()
{
   Search("Micro*").Dump();
}

public Organization Search(string search)
{
   return CreateOrganization(code: search);
}

static Organization CreateOrganization(string code = null){
   var faker = new Faker();
   //setup complicated child dependency graphs here.
   //then finally create your parent object below.
   return new Organization{
      Code = code ?? faker.Company.CompanyName()
   };
}

public class Organization
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

- If you are generating POCO/DTO type of objects that don't have a very large or complicated object graph, then using `Faker<T>` should work really well too. For example:

```cs
void Main()
{
   Search("Micro*").Dump();
}

public Organization Search(string code){
   var customOrgFaker = Fakers.OrgFaker.RuleFor(x => x.Code, f => code);
   return customOrgFaker.Generate();
}

static class Fakers{

   public static Faker<Organization> OrgFaker => 
             new Faker<Organization>()
                 .RuleFor(o => o.Code, f => f.Company.CompanyName());

}
```

[image]

Notice, in the `Faker<T>` example above, I'm calling `.RuleFor(_ => _.Code, ...)` twice, but only the very last call to `.RuleFor` will apply. In this case `.RuleFor(x => x.Code, f => code)` is the last call before `.Generate()`. Effectively, this is like overriding the default `.RuleFor(o => o.Code, f => f.Company.CompanyName())` setup in the static constructor of `Fakers`.

Also note, each time the `.OrgFaker` property is accessed, a `new Faker<T>` is created. This is nice because each property access to `.OrgFaker` creates a dedicated instance of `Faker<T>` for your consumption and customization.

If this doesn't work for you and you only have one instance of `Faker<T>` to work with, you can use the `Faker<T>.Clone()` method to clone the `Faker<T>` and again, call `.RuleFor` with divergent rule without messing up the original instance of `Faker<T>`.

#### Parting advice...

Bottom line, using any method described above, your top priority should be to keep your code clean, clear, and readable. Strive for the simplest and most maintainable solutions.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great thank you! I ended up implementing something similar to this but will refactor based on your advice.